# Updating Database Record in SQL Server with Entity Framework and ASP.Net

Tags: c#, asp.net-mvc, entity-framework

I am working on an ASP.Net MVC CRM-type application using Entity Framework. I have created a model for `Services` which contains some properties such as `DateStarted`, `DateEnded`, `Active` and `Deleted`. Essentially I do not want to actually delete a service should one need to be cancelled, so I am tracking state using the Active and Deleted properties.

I put in some logic so when the `DateEnded` property is entered and is past the current date, it will update the record for that `Service` to have Active = 0, and Deleted = 1. I am looping through all of the Services in one of the Views, and showing each one and some properties, including a `Status` which will be **Active** or **Cancelled**. The problem is that when one of these services gets Deleted set to 1 or Active set to 0, it removes it from the list of services and no longer gets rendered in the View. I also tried only setting Active = 0 and leaving Deleted as 0, and that also caused the issue.

Is this something that is built into Entity? I have not yet tried to do this in an Entity ORM so I am not sure if it is something that is a known thing. Is there any way to prevent that from happening?

In the view, the only conditional I am setting is changing a span that gets rendered based on the state of the service, like so:

```
<div class="status">
    @if(service.Active == 1 && service.Deleted == 0)
    {
        <span class="active">Active</span>
    } else {
        <span class="cancelled">Cancelled</span>
    }
</div>
```

The different classes are really just there for styling purposes to change what it looks like for an active service vs a deleted service. Any help into this would be greatly appreciated!

Comment: _"it removes it from the list of services and no longer gets rendered in the View"_ how do you initially populate this list? Your question does not show a list nor any EF code.

Comment: @Jasen I actually just realized that the Repository pulls in services that have `Active` = 1 and `Deleted` = 0 so disregard I am going to close this out. Thank you for your comment it made me dig into it again and I saw what I obviously missed before!